# Cannot store all updates on a key to the store when using Mapstore write behind with setWriteCoalescing to FALSE

Tags: multithreading, hazelcast

In multi threaded environment, using Entry Processor to update the value for an object and using Mapstore Write behind strategy for persistence. Setting setWriteCoalescing to FALSE because I want to store all the updates on key. But its applying only the last update to persistent DB.

Using 3.4.1 hazelcast version.

```
**Map Store Config**:
MapStoreConfig mapStoreConfig = new MapStoreConfig();
mapStoreConfig.setClassName("Class Name");
mapStoreConfig.setEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
mapStoreConfig.setWriteDelaySeconds(1);
mapStoreConfig.setWriteBatchSize(100);
mapStoreConfig.setWriteCoalescing(false);
mapConfig.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreConfig);

**AdjustmentStore Implementation**
public class AdjustmentStore implements MapStore<LocationKey, Adjustment> {
    @Override
    public void store(LocationKey key, Adjustment adjustment) {
        System.out.println("Map Store: store");

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        if(adjustment != null) {
                String url = "http://server_name/xxxxxx";
                 try{
                     System.out.println("Map Store: store rest");
                     restTemplate.put(url, ajustment);
                 }
                 catch(Exception ex) {
                     LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
                     try {
                        throw new Exception("IO error thrown from: " + this.getClass().toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
        }
    }}

**Entry Processor Implementation**
@Override
    public Object process(Entry<Key, Adjustment> entry) {
        Adjustment adjustment = entry.getValue();

        if(adjustment == null) {
            adjustment = updatedAdjustment;
        }
        else {
            adjustment.updateAdjustment(updatedAdjustment.getAdjustment());
        }

        entry.setValue(adjustment);

        return adjustment;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a todo in the source about it already: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.4.1/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/map/impl/mapstore/writebehind/WriteBehindStore.java#L85

So currently it is not yet supported on EP, sorry. Created an issue for it: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/4957